# SQL CURRENT_DATE not gathering result I expect

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Three key bits of detail.

1. I am doing this directly via the SQL query function in phpMyAdmin
2. The query being run is as below:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM `leaderboard` 
   WHERE date > (CURRENT_DATE() - 30) 
   ORDER BY time DESC
   ```
3. My data is as follows:

   ```
   id  room  team                    time  fte  date
   46  adod  Old But Amazing         372   0    2016-07-04 15:13:56
   40  adod  The Inappropriates      315   0    2016-08-22 15:11:58
   41  adod  Chelsea Hens            254   0    2016-08-22 15:12:13
   42  adod  Serco-Top Of The Board  221   0    2016-08-22 15:12:44
   43  adod  Gradually Escaping      165   0    2016-08-22 15:13:05
   44  adod  The Lamb Marlborough    105   0    2016-08-22 15:13:29
   45  adod  Failure                 0     1    2016-08-22 15:13:38
   ```

This is all of the data in my table but is also the exact response I get when I run this query. What confuses me is that the current date (2016-08-16) is at least 40 days beyond 2016-07-04 so why is ID 46 being pulled through as a valid result?

Update: Also, a query of

```
    SELECT * FROM `leaderboard` 
    WHERE date > (CURRENT_DATE() - 20) 
    ORDER BY time DESC
```

will not return ID 46

Comment: SQL-server or mysql?

Comment: What is the data type of your `date` column?

Comment: mysql I believe sorry, misleading tag!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of:

```
(CURRENT_DATE() - 30)
```

Use:

```
SUBDATE(CURRENT_DATE(), 30)
```

This is because the first expression uses the current date as a number in the YYYYMMDD format, i.e. 20160822, and then subtracts 30 from that, giving 20160792, and consequently unexpected results.

Answer (score 1):

`DATE` is a reserved word in MySQL, it evaluates to the current date.

So, your `WHERE` statement is constant, it could have just as well been `WHERE 5 > 1`.  It will always select all rows.

Try a different name for that column.

Comment: I have just updated the collumn name to 'added' and tried 20 and 30 producing exactly the same results as above

Comment: well, it was worth trying. C-:=